# sourcetree - enter passphrase for key after restarted

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, sourcetree, passphrase

I'm using Sourcetree for Bitbucket and Github
I completed setup but when I restart PC, Sourcetree require passphrase for key

How I can save passphrase in Sourcetree and autoload no need enter everytime restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can save passphrase in Sourcetree and autoload no need enter everytime restart?

That seems expected, as the ssh-agent (which should launch with SourceTree) will [cache your passphrase once per session](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases/) (not forever: that wouldn't be very secure)

Comment: I tried this tutorial before I reinstall SourceTree, but it didn't work, it still ask  passphrase?

Comment: @KenLam it should ask the passphrase once per session, not once every request.